# check whether a folder exists with name using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How to check whether a folder exists in google drive with name using python?

I have tried with the following code:

```
import requests
import json

access_token = 'token'

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files'

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token
 }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to know whether a folder is existing in Google Drive using the folder name.
- You want to achieve it using the access token and `requests.get()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- You can search the folder using the query for filtering the file of drive.files.list.

  - In your case, the query is as follows.

    - `name='filename' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`
  - If you don't want to search in the trash box, please add `and trashed=false` to the query.
- In order to confirm whether the folder is existing, in this case, it checks the property of `files`. This property is an array. If the folder is existing, the array has elements.

#### Modified script:

```
import requests
import json

foldername = '#####' # Put folder name here.

access_token = 'token'
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}  # Modified
query = {'q': "name='" + foldername + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"}  # Added
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query)  # Modified
obj = response.json()  # Added
if obj['files']:  # Added
    print('Existing.')  # Folder is existing.
else:
    print('Not existing.')  # Folder is not existing.
```

#### References:

- [drive.files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @kkr Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this [sample code](https://gist.github.com/jmlrt/f524e1a45205a0b9f169eb713a223330) on how to check if destination folder exists and return its ID.

```
def get_folder_id(drive, parent_folder_id, folder_name):
    """ 
        Check if destination folder exists and return it's ID
    """

    # Auto-iterate through all files in the parent folder.
    file_list = GoogleDriveFileList()
    try:
        file_list = drive.ListFile(
            {'q': "'{0}' in parents and trashed=false".format(parent_folder_id)}
        ).GetList()
    # Exit if the parent folder doesn't exist
    except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as err:
        # Parse error message
        message = ast.literal_eval(err.content)['error']['message']
        if message == 'File not found: ':
            print(message + folder_name)
            exit(1)
        # Exit with stacktrace in case of other error
        else:
            raise

    # Find the the destination folder in the parent folder's files
    for file1 in file_list:
        if file1['title'] == folder_name:
            print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
            return file1['id']
```

Also from this [tutorial](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/88814/pydrive.drive.GoogleDrive), you can check if folder exists and if not, then create one with the given name.