# create folder if not exist on google drive with Curl php

Tags: php, curl

I'm uploading files to google drive through Curl php. But now I need to upload all these files in specific folder eg: "My Folder"
I need to get all root folders and evaluate if "My folder" isn't exist on google drive.

#### For first step. I need get all folders in root of google drive

I've founded this function in ahother post

```
public function getAllGoogleDriveFolders($token)
    {
        echo "Buscando Folders en Drive \n";
        $folderID = "root";
        $folderName = "My Folder";
        $baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
        $query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and name='$folderName' and '$folderID' in parents";
        $url = $baseUrl . "?q=" . urlencode($query);
        //print_r($url);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump($response);die();
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

but this function returns "files": [] empty.

```
string(72) "{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": []
}
```

Once I get all folders,

#### Second step, is evaluate these folders

```php
foreach ($data as $folder) {
    if ($folder["name"] != "My Folder") {
        //.. steps to create folder with name My folder and get its fodler_id
    } else {
        // if folder exists in google drive // get the folder id 
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using service account for authenticate. and the app is old for this reason I can't use the php service package.

thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you can provide the mimeType `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` to restrict results to folders. These answers are written in Python but you should be able to follow along, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56532379/296555 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231668/296555

Comment: I've modified the code incoroporing the application/vnd.google-apps.folder
Now returns a Kind Filelist but stil files empty